# Tag synonym requests: Merge [allowed-topics] to [on-topic]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Before things get out of hand, I'd like a tag synonym for [allowed-topics](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) to [on-topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic).

Currently the Gaming Meta has [topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topic), [off-topic-content](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic-content), and [allowed-questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-questions); if we catch this early we could avoid a similar fate.

Comment: The correct tagging is [tag:on-topic]. Please use [tag:on-topic] as the parent tag when the synonym request occurs that way we can fix the FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what's done on the [main Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags), the main tag should be [scope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope), and any other tag that creeps up, such as [allowed-questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) or [on-topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic) or [allowed-topics](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-topics), should be made a synonym of [scope](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope).